# Django rest framework XLSX renderer + Apiview

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-drf-renderer

I'm setting up an endpoint on my API which should return a XLSX-file. The DRF-docs mention https://github.com/wharton/drf-renderer-xlsx as the main external rendering package, aside from the pandas which also seem to be able to render XLSX.

In their code example they use a ReadOnlyViewset paired with a mixin, but there is no mention of how it's used with APIViews. Still, I would like to use an APIView as shown by this https://harshahegde.dev/rendering-xlsx-files-in-django-rest-framework-ckagk293p00eumks1bf4dlhie
However..
This works great when using CURL or Postman, but when done through a browser I get this error:

```
'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'
```

From what I understand this is because there is no Accept header set (e.g 'Accept':'application/xlsx')
I fixed this by removing the Mixin from the renderer_classes, so it simply returns a file called "xlsx" but I can't figure out how to set the filename without the mixin. How do I set the filename using an APIView trying to access the URL from a browser?

My view:

```
class SomedataXlsx(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [XLSXRenderer, JSONRenderer]

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Somedata.objects.all()
        serializer = SomeDataSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the mixin code it became clear they change the content-disposition header, and so since the DRF Response() takes a header argument I tried changing it, and it worked perfectly.

```
class SomedataXlsx(APIView):
renderer_classes = [XLSXRenderer, JSONRenderer]
def get(self, request):
    user_sub_fund_data = Somedata.objects.all()
    serializer = SomeDataSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, headers={"content-disposition":"attachment; filename=mynewfilename.xlsx"})
```